# Replace accented letters with the respective non-accented ones at Python 3

Tags: python, replace, diacritics

I am not sure that this popular [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2633310/9024698) works in Python 3 since there is no unicode in Python 3.

Therefore, how can replace accented letters with the respective non-accented ones at Python 3?

For example,

```
sentence = 'intérêt'
```

to

```
new_sentence = 'interet'
```

Comment: `unidecode` is a third-party module that work just fine in Python3. It's independent of the renaming of Python 2's `unicode` type to `str`.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/33328702/5320906

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked answer references the third-party module `unidecode`, not Python 2's `unicode` type.

```
$ python3
Python 3.7.1 (default, Nov 19 2018, 13:04:22)
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import unidecode
>>> unidecode.unidecode('intérêt')
'interet'
```